# Can I compile fortran programs from cmd without opening the force 2.0 application?

Tags: fortran, fortran90, fortran77

I use force 2.0 compiler to run my fortran programs. Can I use command prompt to do it instead of opening the gui?

Comment: Force 2.0 was an IDE.  It uses g77 or gfortran internally.

Comment: Thanks for the response bud. Any way how I call g77 from command prompt?

Comment: @MadhurjyaSharma it depends on how the compiler is set up. If it is setup properly, typing `g77 -o myprogram.exe mysourcecode.f90` should do what you want.

Comment: In any case, there are windows binaries for gfortran, which is a very good open source compiler https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranBinaries